# How do I get Evolution to apply filters automatically?

Tags: configuration, evolution, email

I am using an IMAP email account. I created a filter in Evolution to move email from a specific high-volume source into a particular folder, to keep the Inbox uncluttered. I noticed that incoming emails are coming straight into the Inbox. If I select Messages->Apply Filters, then they are moved into the folder. Is there an option to make this filtering apply automatically to all new emails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a setting in the account configuration somewhere where you can switch filtering on/off for that account.  Maybe check if it's on?

Comment: That's it. Full instructions : Edit -> Preferences -> Mail Accounts -> (select account) -> Edit -> Receiving Options -> Apply filters to new messages in INBOX on this server.